# L={a^i b^j c^k d^l | i=k and j=l} i couldn't find the grammar of the given language

Tags: regular-language, automata, automata-theory

I have tried

```
S-A|B
A-aCcD|aAc|ac
B-bBd|bd
C-b
D-d
```

this to only to output ac and bd's but I can't put b's between a and c's.

Comment: please add more description

Comment: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/design-grammar-language-show-derivation-word--a2b3c2d3-l4-b-cked-k-j-1-b-design-npda-follo-q51078652 it's the first question in here. I guess it's a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the string a^p b^p c^p d^p. This string is surely in the language. If the language were regular, and there existed a regular grammar for it, then it would satisfy the requirements of the pumping lemma for regular languages: namely, the string given above could be written as uvx where |uv| <= p, |v| > 0 and for all natural numbers n, u(v^n)x is also in the language. There are seven cases for what v contains: just a; a and b; just b; b and c; just c; c and d; or just d. In any case, pumping v will change the number of instances of one kind of symbol but not the number of instances of the corresponding symbol (the one the language requires be exactly as frequent). So, the language cannot be regular.

Similarly, the pumping lemma for context-free languages would require that the string given above be written as uvxyz where |vxy| <= p, |vy| > 0 and for all natural numbers n, u(v^n)x(y^n)z is also a string of the language. We get exactly the same cases here as above and reach exactly the same conclusion: the language cannot be context-free.

Given all this, we might as well just target an unrestricted grammar (it might be possible to get a context-sensitive grammar for this language, but that is not requested). We want the same number of a and c, and the same number of b and d, and we want them to be in alphabetical order. We can start out like this:

```
S -> ACS | BDS | T
```

This lets us get strings with the same number of A as C, and the same number of B as D, ending with T. Next, we need some rules to allow putting the symbols A, B, C and D in the right order:

```
BA -> AB
CA -> AC
DA -> AD
CB -> BC
DB -> BD
DC -> CD
```

Finally, we need a way to convert the non-terminals A, B, C and D to terminals a, b, c and d in such a way that it can't work unless they're all in order. We can use T (and a few other symbols to be introduced soon) to sweep from right to left, converting as we go:

```
DT -> Td
CT -> Uc
BT -> Vb
AT -> Wa
T -> e

CU -> Uc
BU -> Vb
AU -> Wa
U -> e

BV -> Vb
AV -> Wa
V -> e

AW -> Wa
W -> e
```

Nonterminals T, U, V and W allow converting A-D, A-C, A-B and A to a-d, a-c, a-b and a, respectively. We can also get rid of this marker symbol at any time. The only way to eliminate all nonterminals and get a string of terminals (that is, to generate a string according to this grammar) is to sweep from right to left, converting all encountered symbols, and finally use whichever of the X -> e rules is needed to eliminate the marker. This can only work if the symbols were converted in descending order from right to left, so they must be in ascending order from left to right, as required. Because the productions for S introduce A, C and B, D in matched pairs, that requirement is satisfied as well.

Comment: Ah, the context-free pumping lemma. Haven't seen that in a while!